# Compiling and running jacorb's demo

Tags: java, ant, jacorb

I installed jacorb successfully. How can I compile and run the demo exemples ?I build the demo with ant, it generate a build file, and then ?

Comment: Does it generate a jar file? .class files? is there an ant task to run the program itself?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated what version of JacORB you are using.

It should generate a number of classes in the build directory. It can either run the entire client/server automatically or you can run it manually.

Add that build/classes to you classpath and then execute the demo by
    jaco demo.hello.Server
and then
    jaco demo.hello.Server

I would recommend asking any JacORB questions on the jacorb-developer mailing list http://www.jacorb.org/contact.html